# Cubic surfaces and 27 lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cubics

It is well known that a smooth cubic surface will contain 27 lines. All the references I came across gives a proof of the fact for fields of Characteristic $\neq 2$. Is there a reference where the characteristic 2 case is proved?